# Is there any way to load pre-rendered svg from the server into the Polymaps?

Tags: polymaps

I need to render 30000 grid cells (polygon) into a Polymap map. Is there any way to load pre-rendered svg from the server into the Polymap?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by grid cells? Also, how is your data stored on the server? It might also help to provide an example of the code that you are using to load the data at the moment.

Comment: Essentially its a grid. Polymaps renders it as 30000 square polygons arranged as a grid. I recently changed from using non-tiled geojson to using tiled and saw a pretty big performance improvement. It works reasonably good in Chrome but in Firefox the slippy action of the maps is quite jumpy and doesn't animate properly. Don't think this question is really valid any more but would be nice to have a svg layer that you could load directly from the server in cases where the rendering is static and complex.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up loading the data as vector tiles generated by tilestache which performed much better. Issue now is the general responsiveness of the map in terms of panning and zooming. Google Chrome performs well beyond any other browser tested. Chrome even performs better with 30k features than Firefox with 5k.